# Receiving "Segmentation fault" when attempting to insert keys in hash table

Tags: c, memory, hash, linked-list, hashtable

I'm attempting to implement open hashing in C using a linked list struct I've already made. The linked list struct works perfectly, however when trying to use them in my hash table struct, I'm constantly given "Segmentation fault (core dumped)"

I've already checked to make sure that I'm using the proper data types and I'm allocating the right amount of memory.

```
typedef struct LinkedList LinkedList;

LinkedList* createLinkedList(){
    LinkedList* rslt = malloc(sizeof(Node*)); //Allocate memory for LL
    //rslt->head = calloc(1,sizeof(Node*)); //Allocate memory for head with default Node* value (NULL)
    return rslt;
}

void add_end_LinkedList(LinkedList* x, int v){

    //Special case: LinkedList is empty
    if(x->head == NULL)
        x->head = createNode(v);

    else{
        //Traversing to end of list
        Node* p;
        for(p = x->head; p->next != NULL; p = p->next){1;}
        p->next = createNode(v);
    }
}

void add_beg_LinkedList(LinkedList* x, int v){
    Node* p;

    //Special case: LinkedList is empty
    if(x->head == NULL)
        x->head = createNode(v);

    else{
        p = createNode(v);
        p->next = x->head;
        x->head = p;
    }
}

int isIn_LinkedList(LinkedList* x, int v){
    for(Node* p = x->head; p != NULL; p = p->next){
        if(p->val == v) return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}

void print_LinkedList(LinkedList* x){
    for(Node* p = x->head; p != NULL; p = p->next){
        print_Node(p);
        printf(", ");
    }
    printf("\n");
    return;
}

//HASHTABLE_____________________________________________________________

struct HashTable{
    LinkedList** table;

};

typedef struct HashTable HashTable;

HashTable* createTable(){
    HashTable* rslt = {calloc(9,sizeof(LinkedList*))};

    for(int i = 9; i < 9; i++)
        rslt->table[i] = createLinkedList();

    return rslt;
}

int compute_hash(int v){
    return v%9;
}

int isIn_HashTable(HashTable* x, int v){
    return isIn_LinkedList(x->table[compute_hash(v)], v);
}

int insert_HashTable(HashTable* x, int v){
    if(isIn_HashTable(x, v)){
        return 0;
    }

    add_beg_LinkedList(x -> table[compute_hash(v)], v);
    return 1;
}

int main(void){
    HashTable* a = createTable();
    insert_HashTable(a, 6);
    return 0;
}
```

createTable() does not raise any runtime errors. But any other HashTable functions do. I'm not able to access the linked lists in the table.

Comment: You may find [Coding up a Hash Table](http://www.sparknotes.com/cs/searching/hashtables/section3.rhtml) and [Hash tables - eternally confuzzled](http://eternallyconfuzzled.com/tuts/datastructures/jsw_tut_hashtable.aspx) useful.

Answer (score 0):

Rslt is a pointer. You cannot initialize it the way you initialize struts. After returning from the function the the rslt pointer will become invalid in the following  code

```
 HashTable* createTable(){
     HashTable* rslt = {calloc(9,sizeof(LinkedList*))};
```

{..} is not a dynamic memory allocation. Try to malloc rslt first

```
     HashTable *rslt = malloc(sizeof(HashTable));
     rslt->table = calloc...
```